# PrimeNg doesn't work with Angular: 5.2.9

Tags: angular, primeng

Like in the title I have a problem to PrimeNg, I am using Angular: 5.2.9. I have installed PrimeNg according to this documentation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

I have already added dependencies and styles as they showed and when I am using for example `p-splitButton`

I get such error

> p-splitButton' is not a known element: or Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'p-splitButton'.

I can't even use the button because it's displayed as a normal grey button and I am not able to display a button with the fa-icon.

Comment: have you included it in the [modules](https://yakovfain.com/2016/10/06/primeng-ui-components-for-angular-2/) import?

Comment: Yes I have added both of them in my app.module     StepsModule,ButtonModule

Comment: If you have added it propery, and no error but the app still cannot find it, I suggest deleting the node_modules folder, and `npm install`, then try again.

Comment: It doesn't help I have tried to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-treetable which also based on PrimeNg but an error is the same. It's possible that there is something wrong with that Angular version?

Comment: Ok, I resolve the problem if I am using the Shared module I should import it directly in that module to which component belongs, not to the app.module